# Declare a variable using IBM iSeries Navigator "Run SQL Scripts" utility

Tags: variables, db2, iseries-navigator

I'm new to IBM DB2, using the iSeries Navigator, IBM iSeries Access for Windows Version 5 Release 4, the "Run SQL Scripts" utility.

Is it possible to use a variable in this utility?  A number of Stack Overflow answers (and answers on other forums) instruct one to use code like the following:

```
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE x VARCHAR(1);
SET x = 'A';
SELECT * FROM  MySchema.MyTable Where MyColumn = x;
END@
```

This does not work inside the "Run SQL Scripts" utility, throwing the exception "Token ATOMIC was not valid."  If I remove the keyword ATOMIC I get the error "Token X was not valid."  If I remove the entire BEGIN and END lines I get the error "Token VARCHAR was not valid."

Another set of answers instruct one to use code like the following, which also fails with the same "...not valid" errors:

```
CREATE VARIABLE x VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT ('A');
SELECT * FROM MySchema.MyTable WHERE MyColumn = x;
DROP VARIABLE x;
```

Is it possible to declare variables in the "Run Sql Scripts" utility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global variable support and dynamic compound statement support were added to DB2 for i at 7.1.

Is the system itself still running v5r4?  Or are you just running a back level version of Client Access?  If the later, upgrade your IBM iAccess to 7.1.  If the former, you're SOL until the system gets upgraded.

Comment: Dynamic compound statements would allow local variables inside the score of a BEGIN block. But this feature only became available in 7.1 if you have installed Technical Refresh 7 [TR7].